# извлечение из строки/списка числа больше 9

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть необходимость извлечения из строки/списка числа больше первого порядка без использования стандартных методов split join и всего такого. до десяти работает сравнение с numbers = '0123456789' допустим, а как быть дальше? хелп ми!) мой вариант кода ниже, но он не различает 10(

```
a = input()
b = []
numbers = '0123456789'
for i in a:
    if i in numbers:
        b.append(int(i))
    else:
        continue
print(b)

вход: 3,5,7,9,10
выход: [3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Вы что-нибудь пробовали самостоятельно делать?

Comment: Постарайся переформулировать вопрос, чтобы было понятно, о чем он. С примерами ввода/вывода, собственными попытками и т.д.

Comment: ок, исправил...

Comment: Чем вам не угодили «split join и всё такое»?

Comment: задача такая) вернее даже не в этом задача, но это-основной ключ... интересно же!;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbers = '0123456789'

def qwerty(stri):
    (a, la, stri) = ('', 0, (' ' + stri))
    for (e, s) in enumerate(stri):
        if s in numbers:
            la += 1
            if not a:
                a = e
        elif la > 0:
            if la > 1:
                yield stri[a:e]
            (a, la) = ([], 0)
        continue

    if la > 1:
        yield stri[a:(e+1)]
    return

print(*qwerty('11,3,5,7,9,10,11,2,12,1'))  # 11 10 11 12
```

Comment: спс за вариант! но он не подходит для меня к сожалению( но я попробую извлечь из него полезное для себя;)

Comment: убрал join, смысл в том что надо узнать индексы числа в строке, и если индексов для числа несколько(>9), возвращать срез строки по индексам

Comment: ок, ок, интересно! смысл варианта принят! весьма мерси;) вытаскиваю отсюда то, что если несколько индексов подряд идет число-возвращаю срез!

Answer (score 0):

```
input_data = '1A23D56R4ASDF12345S112'
result = []

add = False
base = 1
for ch in reversed(input_data):
    try:
        num = int(ch) * base
        if add:
            result[0] += num
        else:
            result.insert(0, num)
            add = True
        base *= 10
    except ValueError:
        add = False
        base = 1

print(result)  # [1, 23, 56, 4, 12345, 112]
```

Comment: спс за помощь, но мне не подходит Ваш вариант к сожалению(

Answer (score -1):

все оказалось гораздо проще. с отрицательными он тоже работает.

```
a = input()
b = []
s = str()
numbers = '-0123456789'
for i in a:
    if i in numbers:
        s += i
        continue
    else:
        if len(s) > 0:
            b.append(int(s))
            s = str()
if len(s) > 0:
    b.append(int(s))
print(b)

вход: 0.[0000[/-1//1000,,[12345ю6789,,
выход: [0, 0, -1, 1000, 12345, 6789]
```